# Documenting Django Rest Framework API

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, documentation

Looking for self describing api for django rest framework application

We are using Django 2 and Django Rest Framework 3.7.3
We are looking to document the api based on view doc strings or meta-data
I have tried drf docs and drf auto docs and there don't seem to support our app
Someone mentioned pydocs, but don't think this will work
Our worse case would be using Sphinx I think

we would like an api that gives an example ideally

Example request:

```
GET /tests HTTP/1.1
```

Example response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
[
    {
        "name": "test1",

    },
    {
        "name": "test2",

    }
]
```

Status Codes:

```
200 OK – List of a tests.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try [drf-yasg](https://drf-swagger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html) which supports the generation of redoc or swagger documentation.